# Cloudwatch monitor for Stl_Load_Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We use Kinesis Firehose to load data into a number of Redshift tables. There are monitors available to see successful deliveries. However, there is no monitor for checking if there are any errors in the delivery - the ones that get recorded to stl_load_errors table.

I do have an option to create a lambda that reads the stl_load_errors table and writes to cloudwatch metrics. But, I would like to know if there is any out of the box solution to monitor it.

Comment: Kinesis streams or firehose?

Comment: @RahulGupta Amazon Kinesis Firehose

Answer (score 0):

Check the Firehose Redshift delivery stream metrics in the monitoring tab 
  **DeliveryToRedshift Success (Average)** 
[image].

Also, you can see  [Monitoring with Amazon CloudWatch Metrics.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch-metrics.html)  
 
Enable error logging if it is not already enabled, and check error logs for delivery failure. [Monitoring with Amazon CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch-logs.html)

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: DeliverToRedshift Success - is only for successful deliveries. It can indicate a gap in successful deliveries, but if you do not have consistent deliveries, it is hard to detect an error. Secondly, I am looking for metrics, not logs. We use metrics to send notifications to Slack. So, logs will not be helpful.